# Adding file to docker container fails elastic search startup (for plugin setup)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to add a custom build plugin to elasticsearch.
This simplified DockerFile works.

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.0
ENV ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" cluster.name=elastic-test-instance
ADD elasticsearch.dev.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

USER root
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/x-pack
USER elasticsearch
```

my elasticsearch.yml is as simple as

```
cluster.name: "elastic-test-instance"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: localhost
```

without changing anything else i am simply trying to add a single file like:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.0
ENV ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" cluster.name=elastic-test-instance
ADD foo.txt /foo1.txt
ADD elasticsearch.dev.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

USER root
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/x-pack
USER elasticsearch
```

just adding that foo1.txt file causes elastic init to fail with the log

```
[2018-02-09T15:38:59,099][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/elastic-test-instance]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/elastic-test-instance]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:260) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:258) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:238) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$6.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:239) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:258) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:238) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$6.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mount point not found
at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileStore.findMountEntry(LinuxFileStore.java:91) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileStore.<init>(UnixFileStore.java:65) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileStore.<init>(LinuxFileStore.java:44) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:51) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:39) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:368) ~[?:?]
at java.nio.file.Files.getFileStore(Files.java:1461) ~[?:1.8.0_92-internal]
at org.elasticsearch.env.ESFileStore.getMatchingFileStore(ESFileStore.java:107) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.getFileStore(Environment.java:340) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodePath.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:258) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:238) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$6.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
... 6 more
```

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong trying to add a simple foo.txt to fail elastic init?

what i actually want to do is:

```
ADD my-cool-plugin.jar /my-cool-plugin.jar
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /my-cool-plugin.jar
RUN elasticsearch-plugin install file:///my-cool-plugin.jar
```